# Are my solutions true?(Set-theory)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let be set $$A=\{1,3,4,6\}, B=\{2,4,6\},C=\{1,2,3,4\}$$ What are the elements of the following sets?
$$\overline A \cap(B \triangle C) $$

$$A \setminus (\overline B \cup C)$$

$$(A \setminus \overline C) \cup(C \setminus \overline B) $$

I get for all of these examples the "empty set" am I right?

Comment: If you talk about the complement of a set, you must have some sort of underlying space, that with respect to which the complement is taken.

Comment: I asked exactly because of it this question, in the text of the exercise it's not mentioned from which space do we take the elements.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can do it just by using the fact that element isn't in that set. Then it would make sense to get that each one of those is the empty set.

Comment: I think in the second one you have a $6$.

Comment: what is your try? just use definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got.

$$\overline A \cap(B \triangle C) = \emptyset$$

$$A \setminus (\overline B \cup C) = \{6\}$$

$$(A \setminus \overline C) \cup(C \setminus \overline B) =\{6\}\cup\{2,4\} = \{2,4,6\}$$